# Linkedin V2 API

Tags: rest, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I have created new application on Linkedin. My app uses people current position info to assist the find job.
I want to access the Postion info of user (considering i have access token for it) using linkedin API. I am using Linkedin V2 API.
I have received default permissions of:

```
r_emailaddress
r_liteprofile
w_member_social
```

I am confused because of documentation by linkedin. In some places its written that you have by-default access to r_basicprofile  from which i can get position info, but i didn't got it.

1) What is difference between r_basicprofile and r_fullprofile in Linkedin API V2 ?
2) Do i have to be Linkedin partner for having permissions for r_basicprofile or r_fullprofile in Linkedin API V2 ?
3) Which partner program (Talent Solutions Partnership / Marketing Developer Program ) gives above permissions ?

I have also ticked for *Marketing Developer Platform • Development tier* below *Select the products that you'd like to add/integrate into your app*, while creating app. And i have received survey form in mail regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) and 3) Yes, you need to subscribe or add the product Marketing Development Program in order to receive more permissions for your application.

Here you can find an answer to question 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/ go to permissions and then read about fullprofile, basic profile and lite profile.

First complete the survey as truthful as possible and they will respond to you and you will get the permissions for r_basicprofile, r_emailadress, r_organizations, r_liteprofile and many more. But if you do not add this product you will only be able to have those permissions.

Hope this answers your question!